# How to temporarily disable scrolling of webpage when displaying a dialog box?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

How can I disable scrolling of webpage when displaying a dialog box. I want to avoid using `modal=true` here, as it does not allow me to keep the other sections of the page to be active.

I want to keep both the visible section of the webpage as well as the dialog box to be active but want to disable scrolling of page for the time overlay is displayed.

Comment: This is not a common interaction pattern and would likely just confuse users. I would probably just be annoyed if this were the case - it would see arbitrary and/or broken. How about using a modal dialog which contains all of the relevant UI elements?

Comment: @Matt Ball: My designer instructs so.. and I need to follow that. and I too believe it is wont be problematic for our specific situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this approach, instead, put your dialog box in a div with `position: fixed`

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
```